# * vs ** vs *** in Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

What is the difference between the `*`, `**` and `***` wildcards in Proguard? For example:

```
-keep class com.mypackage.*
```

vs

```
-keep class com.mypackage.**
```

vs

```
-keep class com.mypackage.***
```

Comment: https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#classspecification

Answer (score 0):

from this [the document](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#classspecification) :

```
*   matches any part of a class name not containing the package separator. For example, "com.example.*Test*" matches "com.example.Test" and "com.example.YourTestApplication", but not "com.example.mysubpackage.MyTest". Or, more generally, "com.example.*" matches all classes in "com.example", but not in its subpackages.
**   matches any part of a class name, possibly containing any number of package separators. For example, "**.Test" matches all Test classes in all packages except the root package. Or, "com.example.**" matches all classes in "com.example" and in its subpackages.
***   matches any type (primitive or non-primitive, array or non-array).
```